# Using ord() with ascii tab, enter, etc

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading in a file with 7 columns and a few thousand lines which is output by a third party software program for a logic analyzer. The software has a few glitches where it outputs a value in ASCII rather than decimal, and my goal with this Python script is to convert these ASCII values to decimal. Currently, I have:

```
        seg[4] = str(ord(seg[4]))
```

which is inside of a loop, and seg[] consists of all 7 columns, which are written to the new file one line at a time. This works perfectly until I run into an ASCII tab or enter (\t or \r), which is saved as "\\t", and I get the error "TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found". I have tried setting the value equal to a string with the "repr()" command, but this hasn't worked either. Is there a good way to go about solving this?

---

Here are 4 sample lines :

```
-0.000000162000,0,'14',Rd,'29',0x0,'2'
0.0000907880000,3,'7',ExtWr,'29','3',; 4 '20' '0'
0.0001285000000,8,\t,Rd,'29',0x0,'20'
0.0005672700000,25,'1',ExtWr,d,'0','128'
```

Comment: can you maybe post such a line?

Comment: Here are a sample 4 lines:
-0.000000162000,0,'14',Rd,'29',0x0,'2'
0.0000907880000,3,'7',ExtWr,'29','3',; 4 '20' '0'
0.0001285000000,8,\t,Rd,'29',0x0,'20'
0.0005672700000,25,'1',ExtWr,d,'0','128'

Comment: Sorry - I can't format the comment very well.  The long decimal number is the beginning of each line, and you can see that it only wrongly outputs ascii about 25% of the time.  The first line is correctly all decimal, the second contains an ascii semicolon and ascii 4 in the last column, the third contains an ascii tab in the third column, and the last contains an ascii d in the fifth column.

Answer (score 4):

Decode first.

```
>>> 'A'.decode('string-escape')
'A'
>>> ' '.decode('string-escape')
' '
>>> '\\t'.decode('string-escape')
'\t'
```

Comment: Not sure what I've done wrong, when I do a `'A'.decode('string-escape')`  it returns an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @Atlas7: Are you running Python 2.x like the question asks for?

Comment: Ah silly me (I was doing it in Python 3.6!). Just tried on Python 2.7. Worked now :) Thanks!